# "All but" idiom or excluding "but" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, ambiguity

I'm having a bit of trouble with this section of a biology paper:

"LSU was amplified in these species using F63.2 and Mollusc28R2, which amplified **all but** ~400 bases at the 3' end of the gene."

Does it mean it amplified *almost* all 400 bases, or every base *except* for those 400.

Thank you in advance. I don't study Biology though, I'm just translating this article for a friend.

Comment: The latter is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"But" here is a preposition (not a conjunction) with the definition:

> Except; apart from; other than.
>   *‘supply currently exceeds demand in all but the most rural areas’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/but)</sub>

Because it means exactly what it says, it's not an idiom either. Nor is it ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

For clarity on the expression itself:

[From Grammarist:](https://grammarist.com/usage/all-but/)

> The adverbial phrase all but (no need to hyphenate it) means almost,
>   nearly, or on the verge of. It signals that the following word is
>   almost but not quite the case. For example, if I say, I all but ran to
>   the door, it means I walked very fast to the door but did not run. Or
>   if I say I’m all but finished making dinner, it means I’m putting the
>   finishing touches on the meal.

In this case, you could rephrase it (at least in your mind) to read:

> "which amplified ***nearly*** ~400 bases at the 3' end of the gene."